# Voltage drops when load connected to ld1117a

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics, low-power, esp8266

Package: LD1117A (package sot223)

Power: USB adapter( mobile charger ) 5.3 V 2 A

When these is not r1 resistor present and adj is connected to ground, Vout is 4.9 V for Vin 5.3 V.

r1 is 120 ohm and r2 is adjusted with 20 k potentiometer to get 3.46 V at output. Then load (essentially esp8266 01) is connected, voltage drops to 0.6v and even on adjusting potentiometer to full 20 k, vout just reaches 0.71 V.

Why is this happening?

How to resolve so that ESP8266-01 gets power up?

[Datasheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00002116.pdf)  See page 12

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much bias current does the ADJ take and how much are you providing? What’s the ADJ voltage loaded/unloaded? What’s the input voltage loaded/unloaded?

Comment: input voltage is same 5.3v from mobile charger. See datasheet for ld1117a. See link in description.

Comment: No, you read it! You’re the one who’s asking for help.

Comment: Your “schematic” says 78xx but your title says 1117. Which is it? Where are your input and output capacitors?

Comment: @winny as you can see in fritzing, connections are same as described in datasheet and voltage out required is also in range . Output voltage required (constant 3.3v) and current draw by esp 800mA at boot and near 150mA in normal operation. Power calculations shows 1.6W at boot and 0.3W at normal operation. Still why voltage drops to 0.6v on connecting esp8266-01 3.3v module

Comment: ld1117 shows as 78xx series package in fritzing. Thats why is wrote ld1117 voltage regulator in text above it. Here pin1- GND/ADJ, pin-2 Vout, pin-3 Vin

Comment: 1.6 W * 110 K/W junction to ambient = thermal protection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76367/discussion-between-devprashant-and-winny).

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor at the output is NOT optional. It is required **for stability** on most LDO regulators, including the semi-LDO LM1117.

However the roughly one diode drop 0.7V output suggests you may have connected the load in reverse and possibly damaged it in the process.

Comment: i will check and let you know

Comment: esp01 is working fine. Checked it by programming with usb to ttl.

Answer (score 0):

With SOT223 1117 having 110 K/W junction to ambient thermal resistance and you are pushing 1.6 W of dissipation, you are hitting the thermal protection which is killing your output.

Your solution will be big heatsink or move to a switch-mode/buck converter.

Comment: my nodemcu developement board has ams1117 3.3v  (which is sot223 1117 fixed voltage package) on board which does not seems to heat up at all.
i am expecting to use adjustable voltage regulator to replace this fixed regulator in my custom circuit.
if this doesn't works i will test with ams1117 3.3v linear voltage regulator before going to buck converters ( switch mode regulator).

Comment: Compare the load currents. You can’t beat physics or argue around the problem.

Comment: You can see nodemcu pics on google. It doesn't need any heat sink at all.

Comment: i know i am doing something very wrong with loads across regulator. Can you point it out ? For reference see the fritzing picture.

Comment: also updated the fritzing with lm1117 regulator although its fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: The figure that you show is for an **adjustable version of regulator**, but you have a **fix 2.5 or 3.3** volt one.

You said in normal condition all thing is ok and the output voltage is 4.9. this means you use "Figure 5. Circuit for increasing output voltage" and "VOUT = VOUT(NOM) + (0 - 5V)" you get 4.9 volts.

If you have adjustable version of this regulator then "VOUT = VREF (1 + R2 / R1) + R2 xIADJ" with R1 = \$\infty\$ then output is around 1.25V

Note: in the fix version of regulator they place setting Resistor on the chip when you place external R this change the internal equivalent R

Answer (score -1):

Try 240 Ohm for R2. 20k for your pot is way too much. In order to get 3.6V at output R2 should be 240 Ohms. When using a 20K pot is going to be very hard to get close to 240 Ohms.

Comment: its possibly precise.